# C++ For range loops with multiple reference values [a, b]

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, c++17, rvalue-reference

I've seen some people talk about the new abstraction of C++17 in for ranged loops, where one can use multiple iterators/values/references:

```
for(auto&& [output1, output2] : container)
{...}
```

I've been trying to find an explanation on Google for it, unsuccessfully, since I believe I'm not using the right terminology. In any case I'd be happy if somebody had a link to the cppreference, as well as answer these questions:

**1.** Are we using "&&" because `[output1, output2]` as a whole is an rvalue?

**2.** Let's assume that `output1` and `output2` are both of type `int`. What is the type of "auto"? In other words, what kind of (rvalue?) object is `[output1, output2]`, in case I wanted to not use "auto" and declare it specifically? (Maybe a tuple?)

**3.** What is happening under the hood? Are two iterators being used behind the scenes (see below)? What would be the non C++17 implementation using real iterator objects?

```
for(Container::iterator it1 =..., Container::iteratorit2 = ...; it1!=..., it2!=...; ++it1, ++it2)
{...}
```

Comment: [structured_binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). (and simpler to see it outside of for loop which is just one possible place to use it).

Comment: The `auto &&[a, b] = ...;` syntax is a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). I'm not familiar enough with them to answer off the top of my head, but that should give you a starting point.

Comment: Also, `auto&&` is a _forwarding reference_, not an rvalue.  Understanding that should cover questions 1. and 2.

Comment: It allows `auto [a, b] = std::pair<int, bool>(42, true);` and `std::map` use `std::pair<const Key, Value>`. (`std::pair` is a tuple-like class).

Comment: Dupe of Q(1,2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728626/do-structured-bindings-and-forwarding-references-mix-well Dupe of Q3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480824/

Comment: Thanks everyone.
Jarod42: defining it with an ```std::pair``` might be allowed, but it might be just casting it to a pair. I'm interested in understanding the intrinsic type of if. But in any case, I think it'll be answered in the documents/references I got.

Comment: @DrewDormann This is pedantic, but I don't believe `auto&&` is formally considered a "forwarding reference". A forwarding reference would deduce PRValues as value types (e.g. `T&& x = 5` as a template will deduce `T` as `int`, not `int&&`) -- but `auto&& x = 5` will have `decltype(x)` as `int&&`. This is just using reference collapsing, which would occur the same if you did `type&&` where `type` was an L or R-value reference.